# Is NSURLCredential secure over https?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, security, https

Is NSURLCredential a safe way to send a password over a https connection when responding to a authentication challenge? I assume that this sends the user name and password in a safe way, aka. encrypted and not just as parameters in the url - is this correct?

Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Yes it is.
NSURLCredential is secure if you answer the delegate method properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you answer the delegate method, it is passed securely.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
NSString *user = you user
NSString *password = you pass;

NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:user
                                                         password:password
                                                      persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
[[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

}
```